# Ember 2.0 : why my action is not triggered in route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to move a test app from Ember 1.0 to Ember 2.0

I wrote an index template, with an action event 'alert'

```
<table id="t01">
      <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th>
      </tr>
      {{#each model as |item|}}
        <tr>
          <td {{action "alert" "alert form company name" }}>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
</table>
```

I wrote an application.js controller to initialise the properties

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  className:"hide",
  message: ""
});
```

I also have an index.js controller to perform some logic at the index controller level

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    alert: function(){
      console.log("do some controller level processing");
      return true;
    } 
  }
});
```

and finally I have a routes/application.js with an 'alert'  event handler defined, to update the application controller properties ( className , message)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions:{
    alert: function(message){
      var applicationController = this.controllerFor("application"); 
      applicationController.set("className","alert"); 
      applicationController.set("message",message);
      Ember.run.later(function(){
        applicationController.set("className","hide");
      },2000);
    }
  }
});
```

and a routes/index.js to serve the model data

but it's not working correctly  in Ember.js 2.0  ( running 2.4.2)
and there is no error message in the console, I only get the index controller console log output

it seems that the alert action in the routes/application.js is triggered, receiving correctly the message , but the properties are not set... 
can I get the application controller ? with

```
var applicationController = this.controllerFor("application");
```

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

solved

the application template did not have the correct class ( "className" attribute  in the div ...  so the alert action was correctly handled but no changes happen in the template..